# How to make an uninstaller in java

Tags: java, desktop-application, uninstallation

How to make an uninstaller ( for windows ) in java,
i know the way how i should delete files, i just want to know how to put the uninstaller in the 'delete programs' section of the configuration screen,

Please do read the question, we do not want answers for software to make an installer, since we have already written our own program, we are a group of students with an interested spirit, so we wish to write these things ourselves, and don't want some software from someone else.

kind regards
jonathan

Comment: Hey, Jonathan did you find any way to make an uninstaller? I want to ask for a password when the user tries to uninstall my application. Any idea how can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Please, do *not* write an installer by yourself.  It looks deceptively simple, but isn't.

Either let the user launch your program through Java WebStart (which doesn't look like a Windows system but is acceptable for a central distribution model), or use one of the many existing installers which support Java.

Note:  If you target enterprises, choose one that generates MSI.  These can be centrally installed silently.

Comment: I do ask for an answer to make an Uninstaller, the installer is already finished

Comment: Don't.  The intricate details of how to do it right, and registering it correctly with the operating system is a non-trivial job.

Answer (score 1):

You should not have written your own installer in the first place.

Throw it away, and use a professionally-written installer generator to generate an installer (which will include the uninstaller.)

I recommend [Launch4J](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/), or for simpler installations (i.e. no custom install options) [Java Web Start](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Web_Start) may be easier.

Comment: I do ask for an answer to make an Uninstaller, the installer is already finished

Comment: @Jonathan, I know that, and I am suggesting that you discard the "finished" installer and replace it with a proper one.

Comment: So now you are sugesting our installer isn't proper, have you any idea how rude you are.You have no idea about how we even wrote it. So even if we did not write a propper one, do not take the opportunity away to learn, even tho there are better installers out there, you should not answer with an answer like that because we clearly stated we only wanted to learn about the uninstaller, this is an opportunity to learn for us, so if we didn't want to learn from this experience, we would have posed ANOTHER question asking for a program to make an installer, and would have picked the easy way

Comment: @Jonathan, If you want something to learn from then the "use this product" answers may still be appropriate, if those products are open-source and you can learn how to do it by reading their code.  I do not know how to add the entries to the registry, and normally I would let another program do that for me, but if I had to write my own I would start by reading the source of Launch4J.

Comment: thanks, that is an answer but note that in your answer and not after a huge comment, you might learn something from this thread or another one, since we will post a valiable answer if we have one

Answer (score 0):

Izpack allows the creation of cross-platform installers with optional uninstall (under Add/Remove in MS Windows)

Comment: I do ask for an answer to make an Uninstaller, the installer is already finished

Answer (score 0):

Or you can try non-free *Install Anywhere*

Comment: I do ask for an answer to make an Uninstaller, the installer is already finished

Comment: We just need to know how to place the uninstaller in the 'Uninstall programs' folder in windows,

Comment: as far as I know, to remove program from that list, you simply need to remove something from the registry, so I think, to add something there you need to add something to the registry (at least for winXP)

Comment: @Jonathan- You need add a value in the registry. [Check this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa372105(v=vs.85).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

[Java Web Start](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info) offers an uninstall facility.  It also offers the `ExtensionInstallerService` which is intended to perform other set-up/pull-down beyond the standard 'cache or delete classes' (e.g. un/installing a DB).

Here is my [demo. of the `ExtensionInstallerService`](http://pscode.org/jws/api.html#eis).

---

BTW - noting your further comments, I agree with the advice not to go that route.